# distance travelled after nth bounce

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

A ball is thrown vertically to a height of $625$ meters from ground. Each time it hits the ground it bounces $\frac{2}{5}$ of the height it fell in the previous stage. How much will the ball travel during the first $20$th bounces? How can we derive a formula for finding this?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum to $n$th term for a geometric progression?

Comment: How high does it go up the first time? And how high the second time ($\frac{2}{5}$ now enters the picture...)? And the third? Now extrapolate the height of the $n$-th bounce, and sum them all up.

Comment: @thanks,jerry.Just learned the formula now.

Comment: Am I the only one who is confused by the "recreational-mathemtaics" tag?

Comment: @Goos ,That is because I had no other idea what to tag it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula for $n$ bounces for your question: $$\displaystyle 625\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k\right)$$

Comment: I find it interesting that the ball will theoretically bounce an **infinite** number of times, taking around 28.24 seconds (on Earth)  to finish bouncing...  (Measured from initial throw time)